# jQuery select input value from input text generate by php

Tags: php, jquery, select

I have this structure that I generate for each element find by a search

```
<?php foreach ($this->pneumatici as $pneumatico) :?>
<div class="col-md-3 element-form">
    <div class="input-group input-float">
        <input type="hidden" name="codice" value="<?= $pneumatico->codice ?>" id="codice">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantita" value="0" size="1" maxlength="2"
         <?php if ($pneumatico->quantita == 0){
             echo "disabled"
         } ?> >
    </div>
    <?php if ($pneumatico->quantita == 0){
        echo '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-disabled" role="button"><strong>ESAURITO</strong></button>';
    } else {
        echo '<button class="btn btn-primary insert-cart">Aggiungi <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></button>';
    } ?>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I need when user click on one of the generate button with `class='insert-cart'` to put in array these attributes:

- `'#quantita' => val`,
- `'#codice' => val`

How I can do?

I tried in this way, but I can get only the first element value and doesn't work for the others

```
$(".insert-cart").click(function(){
    var quantTot = "";
    $('#quantita').each(function(){
        var quantita = $('#quantita').val();
        quantTot += quantita;
        if (quantita != 0) {
            var id = $('#codice').val();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have more than one #quanita on the page? IDs should be unique. Try changing to class selector

Comment: You're making at least three mistakes. The first is that elements should not share the same ids - use classes or data properties for that. The  second is that you want to access not `$('#quantita').val()`, but rather `$(this).val()`. The third is that you should probably convert the string value to a float or an int as well.

Comment: You are great! I added class to input and get value by that, I used `$(this).val()` and I converted to int the string, now it works great. thanks

Comment: @JoelHinz Please answer the question, doing that the users stop coming here to provide some help to unanswered question.

Comment: @lmgonzalves I didn't think it was good enough to be used as an answer. But I'll convert it to one since it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer.

You're making at least three mistakes. The first is that elements should not share the same ids - use classes or data properties for that. The second is that you want to access not `$('#quantita').val()`, but rather `$(this).val()`. The third is that you should probably convert the string value to a float or an int as well.